# Unable to delete list item in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have added an input box which would print items on submit. After that, I am trying to delete items from the list by adding a delete button. But, the button isn't working. I assume I have applied wrong logic in the onDelete function. I have used the filter function to print out elements which are true. I am not sure what mistake I have done over here.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Result from './Result';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
      this.state={
        addedItems:[],
        emailValue:''
      }
      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.onDelete=this.onDelete.bind(this);
    }

     handleChange(e){
       this.setState({
         emailValue:e.target.value
       })
     }

     handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let items_copy= this.state.addedItems;
      items_copy.push(this.state.emailValue)
      console.log("item copy"+items_copy)
      this.setState({
        addedItems:items_copy,
        emailValue:''
      })
      console.log(this.state.addedItems)
     }

     onDelete(id){
      console.log("deleted clicked")
      let newArray=this.state.addedItems.filter(i=>i!==this.state.addedItems.id)
      this.setState({
        addedItems:newArray
      })
     }
  render() {
    console.log("")
    return (
     <div>
          <Navbar/>
          <Jumbotron>
          <p>
            Enter the things you would like to buy.
          </p>
        </Jumbotron>

        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Control value={this.state.emailValue} onChange={this.handleChange}type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>

        </Form>
        {(this.state.addedItems.length>0)?
        <Result item={this.state.addedItems} onDelete={this.onDelete} />:'empty'  }     
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Result.js

```
 import React from 'react'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

export default function Result(props) {
    const btnStyle={
        marginTop:-7,
        float:'right'
    };
    const {item,onDelete}=props;
    //let show=item.map(item=>item);
    console.log(item) 
    let itemShow = item.map((item, key,id) =>{
     return ( 
         <ListGroup.Item as="li" key={key}>{item}
         <Button onClick={()=>onDelete(id)}style={btnStyle}variant="danger">Delete</Button></ListGroup.Item>
        )})

    return (
        <div>
            <ListGroup as="ul">
                {itemShow}
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let temp = this.state.addedItems;
temp.filter(i=>i.id!==id);
this.setState({
   addedItems: temp
});
```

The first argument from the filter function is the current item, which I'm assuming you're storing objects so the above *should* work. If you want to filter by index the second argument to filter is the index,

```
.filter((item, index)=>{});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. None of the items are being deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace this line in your OnDelete method :

```
newArray=this.state.addedItems.filter(i=>i!==this.state.addedItems.id)
```

By :

```
const index = this.state.addedItems.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(id);
if (index > -1) {
   this.state.addedItems.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Should do the trick ?

According to the definition of [splice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) by Mozilla Developer.

Comment: Stateful properties shouldn't be modified in place like this, they need to be set to another variable, modified, then set into state so that react can determine what has changed and update the view accordingly.